# Laravel - Revised Authentication Controller

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, controller

I'm developing a Social Engineering Awareness Training Application. This is the focus of my thesis for my undergraduate degree. This will be a multi-part review request, however, if you want to see the entire application, it can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/SafePhish/SafePhish_Version2/tree/6766d99810fcd7d9848221103d3d22f0703b2db8). For this request, I'm looking to see how my revised AuthController ([initial request](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154870/laravel-authentication-controller)) is set up and how effective you think it might be. I open to any and all suggestions about any facet of the code.

One question I still have, though, is there any benefit to having my application almost completely static?

Keep in mind that this application is nearly to testing, however, there are a few pieces that might not be polished.

**AuthController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Libraries\Cryptor;
use App\Libraries\ErrorLogging;
use App\Libraries\RandomObjectGeneration;
use App\Models\Sessions;
use App\Models\Two_Factor;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\User_Permissions;
use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use League\Flysystem\Exception;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
/**
 * create
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param   Request         $request
 * @return  User
 */
public static function create(Request $request) {
    try {
        if($request->input('emailText') != $request->input('confirmEmailText')) {
            return redirect()->route('register');
        }

        $email = $request->input('emailText');
        $username = $request->input('usernameText');
        $password = RandomObjectGeneration::random_str(intval(getenv('DEFAULT_LENGTH_PASSWORDS')),true);

        $user = User::create([
            'username' => $username,
            'email' => $email,
            'first_name' => $request->input('firstNameText'),
            'last_name' => $request->input('lastNameText'),
            'middle_initial' => $request->input('middleInitialText'),
            'password' => password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
            'two_factor_enabled' => 0,
        ]);

        EmailController::sendNewAccountEmail($user,$password);
        return redirect()->route('users');

    } catch(QueryException $qe) {
        if(strpos($qe->getMessage(),"1062 Duplicate entry 'admin'") !== false) {
            return redirect()->route('register'); //return with username exists error
        }
        return redirect()->route('register'); //return with unknown error

    } catch(Exception $e) {
        ErrorLogging::logError($e);
        return abort('500');
    }
}

/**
 * authenticate
 * Authenticates the user against the user's database object. Submits to 2FA if they have
 * the option enabled, otherwise logs the user in.
 *
 * @param   Request         $request
 * @return  \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public static function authenticate(Request $request) {
    try {
        $user = User::where('username',$request->input('usernameText'))->first();
        $password = $request->input('passwordText');
        if(empty($user) || !password_verify($password,$user->password)) {
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }

        User::updateUser($user,$user->email,password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT),$user->two_factor_enabled);

        $session = Sessions::where('user_id',$user->id)->first();
        if(!empty($session)) {
            $session->delete();
        }

        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $cryptor = new Cryptor();

        if($user->two_factor_enabled === 1) {
            $twoFactor = Two_Factor::where([
                'user_id' => $user->id, 'ip_address' => $ip
            ])->first();
            if(!empty($twoFactor)) {
                $twoFactor->delete();
            }

            $code = RandomObjectGeneration::random_str(6,false,'1234567890');
            $twoFactor = Two_Factor::create([
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'ip_address' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                'code' => password_hash($code,PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
            ]);

            EmailController::sendTwoFactorEmail($user,$code);

            $newSession = Sessions::create([
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'ip_address' => $ip,
                'two_factor_id' => $twoFactor->id,
                'authenticated' => 0
            ]);

            $encryptedSession = $cryptor->encrypt($newSession->id);
            \Session::put('sessionId',$encryptedSession);

            return redirect()->route('2fa');
        }

        $newSession = Sessions::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'ip_address' => $ip,
            'authenticated' => 1
        ]);

        $encryptedSession = $cryptor->encrypt($newSession->id);
        \Session::put('sessionId',$encryptedSession);

        $intended = \Session::pull('intended');
        if($intended) {
            return redirect()->to($intended);
        }
        return redirect()->route('authHome');

    } catch(Exception $e) {
        ErrorLogging::logError($e);
        return abort('500');
    }
}

/**
 * generateTwoFactorPage
 * Route for generating the 2FA page.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse | \Illuminate\View\View
 */
public static function generateTwoFactorPage() {
    try {
        if(\Session::has('sessionId')) {
            $cryptor = new Cryptor();

            $sessionId = $cryptor->decrypt(\Session::get('sessionId'));
            $session = Sessions::where('id',$sessionId)->first();

            $sessionCheck = self::activeSessionCheck($session);
            if(!is_null($sessionCheck)) {
                return $sessionCheck;
            }

            if(!is_null($session->two_factor_id)) {
                return view('auth.2fa');
            }
        }
        return redirect()->route('login');

    } catch(Exception $e) {
        ErrorLogging::logError($e);
        return abort('500');
    }
}

/**
 * twoFactorVerify
 * Validates the 2FA code to authenticate the user.
 *
 * @param   Request         $request
 * @return  \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public static function twoFactorVerify(Request $request) {
    try {
        if(!\Session::has('sessionId')) {
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
        $cryptor = new Cryptor();

        $sessionId = $cryptor->decrypt(\Session::get('sessionId'));
        $session = Sessions::where('id',$sessionId)->first();

        $sessionCheck = self::activeSessionCheck($session);
        if(!is_null($sessionCheck)) {
            return $sessionCheck;
        }

        $twoFactor = Two_Factor::where([
            'user_id' => $session->user_id, 'ip_address' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
        ])->first();

        if(!password_verify($request->input('codeText'),$twoFactor->code)) {
            return redirect()->route('2fa');
        }

        $session->update([
            'two_factor_id' => null,
            'authenticated' => 1
        ]);

        $twoFactor->delete();

        $intended = \Session::pull('intended');
        if($intended) {
            return redirect()->to($intended);
        }
        return redirect()->route('authHome');

    } catch(Exception $e) {
        ErrorLogging::logError($e);
        return abort('500');
    }
}

/**
 * resend2FA
 * Generates and sends a new 2FA code.
 *
 * @return  \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public static function resend2FA() {
    try {
        if(!\Session::has('sessionId')) {
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
        $cryptor = new Cryptor();

        $sessionId = $cryptor->decrypt(\Session::get('sessionId'));
        $session = Sessions::where('id',$sessionId)->first();

        $sessionCheck = self::activeSessionCheck($session);
        if(!is_null($sessionCheck)) {
            return $sessionCheck;
        }

        $user = User::where('id',$session->user_id)->first();
        if(empty($user)) {
            return self::logout();
        }

        $twoFactor = Two_Factor::where([
            'user_id' => $session->user_id, 'ip_address' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
        ])->first();
        if(!empty($twoFactor)) {
            $twoFactor->delete();
        }

        $code = RandomObjectGeneration::random_str(6, '1234567890');
        Two_Factor::create([
            'user_id' => $session->user_id,
            'ip_address' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
            'code' => password_hash($code,PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
        ]);

        EmailController::sendTwoFactorEmail($user,$code);
        return redirect()->route('2fa');

    } catch(Exception $e) {
        ErrorLogging::logError($e);
        return abort('500');
    }
}

/**
 * activeSessionCheck
 * Helper function to check session objects.
 *
 * @param   Sessions    $session            The session to check.
 * @return  \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse | null
 */
private static function activeSessionCheck(Sessions $session) {
    if($session->ip_address !== $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
        $session->delete();
        \Session::forget('sessionId');
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }

    if($session->authenticated === 1) {
        return redirect()->route('authHome');
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * check
 * Validates if the user is authenticated on this IP Address.
 *
 * @return  bool
 */
public static function check() {
    if(!\Session::has('sessionId')) {
        return false;
    }
    $cryptor = new Cryptor();

    $sessionId = $cryptor->decrypt(\Session::get('sessionId'));
    $session = Sessions::where('id', $sessionId)->first();

    if($session->ip_address !== $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
        $session->delete();
        \Session::forget('sessionId');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * adminCheck
 * Validates if the user is an authenticated admin user.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public static function adminCheck() {
    $check = self::check();
    if(!$check) {
        return $check;
    }

    $cryptor = new Cryptor();

    $sessionId = $cryptor->decrypt(\Session::get('sessionId'));
    $session = Sessions::where('id', $sessionId)->first();

    $user = User::where('id',$session->user_id)->first();
    if(empty($user)) {
        $session->delete();
        \Session::forget('sessionId');
        return false;
    }

    if($user->user_type !== 1) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * logout
 * Removes session variables storing the authenticated account.
 *
 * @return  \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public static function logout() {
    $cryptor = new Cryptor();

    $sessionId = $cryptor->decrypt(\Session::get('sessionId'));
    Sessions::where('id', $sessionId)->first()->delete();
    \Session::forget('sessionId');

    return redirect()->route('login');
}

/**
 * generateLogin
 * Generates the login page.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse | \Illuminate\View\View
 */
public static function generateLogin() {
    if(self::check()) {
        return redirect()->route('authHome');
    }
    return view('auth.login');
}

/**
 * generateRegister
 * Generates the register page if the user is an admin.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse | \Illuminate\View\View
 */
public static function generateRegister() {
    if(self::adminCheck()) {
        $permissions = User_Permissions::all();
        $variables = array('permissions'=>$permissions);
        return view('auth.register')->with($variables);
    }
    return abort('401');
}

/**
 * authRequired
 * Adds session variable for return redirect and then redirects to login page.
 *
 * @return  \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public static function authRequired() {
    \Session::put('intended',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    return redirect()->route('login');
}
}
```

**Random Object Generation Library**

```
<?php

namespace App\Libraries;

use Doctrine\Instantiator\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;


class RandomObjectGeneration
{
const KEYSPACE = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
const PASSWORD_KEYSPACE = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%&';

/**
 * random_str
 * Generates a random string.
 *
 * @param   int                         $length         Length of string to be returned
 * @param   bool                        $passwordFlag   Boolean flag identifying whether string will be a password
 * @param   string                      $keyspace       Allowed characters to be used in string
 * @throws  InvalidArgumentException
 * @return  string
 */
public static function random_str($length, $passwordFlag = false, $keyspace = RandomObjectGeneration::KEYSPACE)
{
    if($passwordFlag) {
        $keyspace = RandomObjectGeneration::PASSWORD_KEYSPACE;
    }
    if(empty($length) || !is_int($length) || $length < 0) {
        $message = 'Random String Generation: Length is Invalid. Length must be a positive integer. Value Provided: ' .
            var_export($length);
        throw new InvalidArgumentException($message);
    }
    if(empty($keyspace) || !is_string($keyspace)) {
        $message = 'Random String Generation: Invalid Keyspace';
        throw new InvalidArgumentException($message);
    }
    $str = '';
    $max = mb_strlen($keyspace) - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
        $str .= $keyspace[random_int(0, $max)];
    }
    return $str;
}
}
```

**Sessions Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Sessions extends Model
{
protected $table = 'sessions';

protected $primaryKey = 'id';

protected $fillable = ['user_id',
    'ip_address',
    'two_factor_id',
    'authenticated'
];
}
```

**ErrorLogging**

```
<?php

namespace App\Libraries;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class ErrorLogging
{
public static function logError(\Exception $e) {
    $message = $e->getCode() . ': ' . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    $message .= $e->getTraceAsString() . PHP_EOL;
    $message .= str_repeat('-',100) . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    Log::error($message);
}
}
```

Comment: why don't you use built in Laravel auth mechanism? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authentication-quickstart

Comment: @DanCantir This is for my undergraduate thesis. Part of the goals are to show functionality and my ability. While the built-in auth is nice, I found that implementing it does benefit me enough for the depth I want to reach. You're more than welcome to propose an answer saying use Laravel auth, but that doesn't answer this question.

Comment: yep, it will not answer the question. I will try to make a review later, assuming it's "forbidden" to use Laravel built in stuffs.

Comment: @Dan not entirely forbidden, just advised against. Using built in can be useful when your taking it and then augmenting it. For instance, my email logic: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154875/email-controller. But other times, it's better to show your intuitiveness and creativity with custom logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer:

**I strongly recommend to use Laravel built in functionalities for this, but since it's "advised against" using it and this is a university work, below is my review:**

Let's start with `AuthController`.

---

`create` method:

This code:

```
if($request->input('emailText') != $request->input('confirmEmailText')) {
    return redirect()->route('register');
}
```

I would suggest first making sure that `email` value is not empty and that is a valid e-mail.

Instead, I would create [a custom `FormRequest`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#form-request-validation).

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CreateUserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true; // Change this as per your needs
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'emailText' => 'required|email',
            'confirmEmailText' => 'same:emailText',
            'usernameText' => 'required',
            //...
        ];
    }
}
```

Then, you can just specify it as a type of your `$request` parameter like this:

```
public static function create(CreateUserRequest $request) {
```

Also, make sure you check the [currently available validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#available-validation-rules) and how to create your own.

For example, this lines:

```
if(strpos($qe->getMessage(),"1062 Duplicate entry 'admin'") !== false) {
            return redirect()->route('register'); //return with username exists error
        }
```

can be avoided with the following rule: `'email' => 'unique:users,username'`

> So, how are the validation rules evaluated? All you need to do is
>   type-hint the request on your controller method. The incoming form
>   request is validated before the controller method is called, meaning
>   you do not need to clutter your controller with any validation logic.

Then, this line:

```
EmailController::sendNewAccountEmail($user,$password);
```

I suggesting using [Eloquent Events and Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events). If you will read the docs, I am sure you will understand how to use them.

---

`authenticate` method:

As i said before, validation should be in a separate `FormRequest`.

Then, instead of `\Session::put('sessionId',$encryptedSession);`
 and `\Session::pull('intended')`

I would suggest using just `session(['sessionId' => '$encryptedSession'])` and `session('intended')`. It looks much more clean.

---

Will update this answer with the review of other methods from this controller shortly.

---

**General:**

Naming conversions: **Use singular nouns for class names.**

So, instead of `SessionsModel`, I would use `SessionModel` or better `Session`. Instead of `ErrorLogging`, I would use `ErrorLogger` or better `Logger`. The same goes for `RandomObjectGeneration`: `RandomObjectGenerator` is better. Nice answer about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361869/php-function-variable-naming).

I have also noticed all your methods are `static`, however I am not sure I understand why.

Comment: Good points with the custom request. However, I don't think I can implement the observer. The way I've got my system set up right now, I email the new user their password. This has to be a decrypted version of the password but for passwords I hash them. One way not two way.